# avoid null tables in left join

Tags: sql, join

If I join two tables together with left join and one of the tables is completely empty, I get a bunch of empty columns in the joined table.

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/67da6/8/1) demonstrating what I mean.

I would like the resulting joined table to not contain all those null columns

Comment: And why do you want to avoid the join?, what is the result that you actually would like?

Comment: An Inner join will only join where there is matching data.  If the table is empty then all the empty columns is what you asked for.

Comment: I'm not trying to avoid the join more like avoid the result containing an empty table

Comment: That's why I asked what would you want as a result in your example

Comment: @MarlinPierce I would just like to avoid the empty columns from coming up in the result because of the empty table. If one of the tables is empty I want to return the non empty table not nothing

Comment: *not contain* all those `null columns` or `null values`?

Comment: @Kaf Columns that are entirely null, I would not like the column to show up at all

Comment: You are not going to get NULL columns omitted from an SQL query.  In particular, the fields you list in the SELECT is what you will get, whether they are NULL for every record or not.

Answer (score 1):

The number of columns that a query returns is fixed.  It cannot change depending on whether a table is empty or not.  So the answer is nope.